# Converting Chinese words from Word to Pinyin, and between traditional and simplified in python

Tags: python

I known that cjklib library it's capable of converting chinese a single character from traditional to simplified and to pinyin, but it can't convert chinese words(specially 2 characters forming a word).

The problems are:
a) Many Chinese characters combine together change the tone.
Ex: 喜->Xǐ   歡->Huān  喜歡->Xǐhuan
(On these example the 2nd character when combine loses the tone)

b) Some simplified characters have different traditional characters depending on the meaning, or the way they combine.
Ex: 面 can become 麵 in traditional chinese, depending one the other character.

So I'm looking for a library for python that is capable of converting from chinese to pinyin, and between simplified and traditional that takes these factors into account.